# Interactions between structures on the same object

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose we have an object with a structure on it. Is there an example of such an object in which it is *useful* to introduce a new structure on it in order to deduce some properties of the first structure.

Examples of an object with different structures on it are: $\mathbb{R}$ with the field structure and the euclidean topology on it; $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ with the group structure considered also like a differentiable manifold.

(If you want I can make this more formal)

Comment: An example:  say you want to prove that the 3-sphere has a trivial tangent bundle.  This is easily seen if you give it the structure of a Lie Group (unit group of quaternions).

Comment: Is there any example where this _doesn't_ happen?  I find it hard to believe you have never seen an example of this before.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest examples is that you have two different algebra structures on a vector space $V$. For example, consider a Lie algebra structure on $V$. Then we introduce a "new" structure on $V$, namely a pre-Lie algebra structure $x\cdot y$ on $V$, interacting with the Lie structure via $[x,y]=x\cdot y-y\cdot x$. It gives interesting informations on the Lie algebra structure.
Furthermore the pre-Lie algebra structure describes a left-invariant affine structure on the connected, simply connected Lie group with the given Lie algebra. In this sense, for example, pre-Lie algebra structures on the reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ describe left-invariant affine structures on the reductive Lie group $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. For details see [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_04_reductive.pdf).
So, more generally, there are interactions between structures on the same object, and on associated objects.